# Uniswap V4 hooks contract address

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap

In [univ4 Hooks](https://github.com/Uniswap/v4-core/blob/main/contracts/libraries/Hooks.sol), they describe that the hooks contract address need to follow the pre-determined rules by the protocol.

What is the purpose of that? And, how can we determine the address of the contract before we deploy?

Does it mean that we need to deploy the contract over and over to get the correct address?

```
/// @notice V4 decides whether to invoke specific hooks by inspecting the leading bits of the address that
/// the hooks contract is deployed to.
/// For example, a hooks contract deployed to address: 0x9000000000000000000000000000000000000000
/// has leading bits '1001' which would cause the 'before initialize' and 'after modify position' hooks to be used. 

...

function shouldCallBeforeInitialize(IHooks self) internal pure returns (bool) {
    return uint256(uint160(address(self))) & BEFORE_INITIALIZE_FLAG != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done for gas efficiency reasons. Instead of reading some flags from storage, which would require SLOAD (gas cost 2100 for cold reads), the code simply looks at the address of the contract itself and performs the binary AND operation, which is much less expensive.

It's correct that the hook contracts must be "mined" - redeployed over and over again on a forked copy of the chain to get the correct contract's address, either by using a deployer's address, increasing the nonce, or if `CREATE2` is used, simply by changing the salt value. It creates some light barriers to deploying new hooks, but then again, a good design of DEX pools is not a trivial thing either.

**Edit:** See [here](https://soliditydeveloper.com/uniswap4) for an example `UniswapHooksFactory` code, at the section "Deploying Hook at the Correct Address".